# Is it possible to get the index in list when I use "if string in list:"?

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
x = ['some', 'fairly', 'long', 'string']
if "fairly" in x:
    return index?
```

Is there an easy way to get the index of "fairly"?

Comment: Yep: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the builtin `index` method in a `try-except` block?

```
lst = ["fairly","blue","car"]
x = "fairly"
try:
   print lst.index(x)
except ValueError:
   print "{0} not in list".format(x)
```

Comment: wow, guess i was stuck on stupid for a while. knew there was some buitlin function for this. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work? This may help in cases where there are multiple occurrences of the word:

```
In [1]: x = ['some', 'fairly', 'long', 'string', 'another', 'fairly']

In [2]: f_places = [index for index, i in enumerate(x) if i == 'fairly']

In [3]: f_places
Out[3]: [1, 5]
```

You could then check using `if f_places:` and return the values accordingly.

Comment: this is good too. i didnt think of multiple occurrences. thank you!

Comment: No problem - @mgilson's way is the 'correct' way though, so good choice :) Good luck!